# how do i fix "cannot read property match of undefned" in this code

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

i'm trying to integrate **nativescript-imagepicker plugin** with my Nativescript App, but i get error **cannot read **property match of undefined****
below is what i have already tried, thanks.

```
function onSelectSingleTap(args) {  
    var context = imagepickerModule.create({
        mode: "single"
    });
    if (platformModule.device.os === "Android" && platformModule.device.sdkVersion >= 23) {   
        permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, "I need these permissions to read from storage")
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Permissions granted!");
            startSelection(context);
        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.log("Uh oh, no permissions - plan B time!");
        });
    } else {
        startSelection(context);
    }
}

function sendImages(selected) {
    let fileUri = selected.fileUri;
    imageName = extractImageName(fileUri);

    var request = {
        url: "http://vvvvvv.com/skog/upload.php",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
            "File-Name": imageName
        },
        description: "{ 'uploading': " + imageName + " }"
    };
    //get the image source and upload from there
    selected.getImage().then(imageSource => {
        let temp = fs.knownFolders.temp();
        let uniqueName = '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
        let filePath = fs.path.join(temp.path, uniqueName + ".jpg");
        let saved = imageSource.saveToFile(filePath, enums.ImageFormat.jpeg);
        console.log(`item saved:${saved}`);
        var task = session.uploadFile(filePath, request);

        task.on("progress", logEvent);
        task.on("error", logEvent);
        task.on("complete", x => cleanFile(filePath));
    });
    //return task;
}
function logEvent(e) {      
        console.log("----------------");
        console.log('Status: ' + e.eventName);
        console.log('Error: ' + e.error);
        // console.log(e.object);
        if (e.totalBytes !== undefined) {
            console.log('current bytes transfered: ' + e.currentBytes);
            console.log('Total bytes to transfer: ' + e.totalBytes);
        }  
    }
function cleanFile(file){
    fs.remove(file);
}
function startSelection(context) {
    context
        .authorize()
        .then(function() {
            imageItems.length = 0;
            return context.present();
        })
        .then(function(selection) {
            selection.forEach(function(selected) {
                sendImages(selected);
                //selected.uploadTask = sendImages(selected);             
                selected.imageName = imageName;

                console.log("----------------");
                console.log("uri: " + selected.uri);           
                console.log("fileUri: " + selected.fileUri);
                console.log('Image name:' + imageName);

                imageItems.push(selected);
            });
            //list.items = selection;
        }).catch(function (e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert(e.message);
        });
}
function extractImageName(fileUri) {
  var pattern = /[^/]*$/;
  var imageName = fileUri.match(pattern);

  return imageName[0];
}
```

I don't think the fault is from the php which is why i'm not adding the code to the question, but if you think otherwise, please let me know
please help

Comment: _`description: "{ 'uploading': " + imageName + " }"`_ — that doesn’t look good. It’s not JSON, and the `imageName` won’t be in quotes. You’re not parsing that in any way, are you?

Comment: Can you verify you're passing a string when calling `extractImageName`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this will do it

```
function onSelectSingleTap(args) {
      var context = imagepickerModule.create({
          mode: "single"
      });

      if (platformModule.device.os === "Android" && platformModule.device.sdkVersion >= 23) {
          permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, "I need these permissions to read from storage")
              .then(function () {
                  console.log("Permissions granted!");
                  startSelection(context);
              })
              .catch(function () {
                  console.log("Uh oh, no permissions - plan B time!");
              });
      } else {
          startSelection(context);
      }
    }


    function startSelection(context) {

      context
          .authorize()
          .then(function () {

              return context.present();
          })
          .then(function (selection) {
            selection.forEach(function(selected) {
              //alert(selected.android.toString()); 
              var file =  selected.android.toString();
              var url = "https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/upload.php";
              var name = file.substr(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
              //alert(name);
              var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");
              var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
              var request = {
              url: url,
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                  "File-Name": name
              },
            description: "Uploading " + name
        };

            var task = session.uploadFile(file, request);
            task.on("progress", progressHandler);
            return task;
            function progressHandler(e) {
              var toast = Toast.makeText("uploaded " + e.currentBytes + " / " + e.totalBytes);
              toast.show();
          }
            });
          }).catch(function (e) {
              console.log(e.eventName);
              alert(e.message);
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`selection` is an array of [ImageAsset](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_asset_.imageasset), so `selected.getImage()` is obviously `undefined`. It has only `getImageAsync(...)` but that returns native image data.

To create [ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/image-source#save-image-from-image-asset-to-png-file) from asset, you should use `fromAsset` method.

`fileUri` is also `undefined`, there is no property as such. I'm not sure where you are picking all these from. I suggest you to refer the documentation for all valid properties and methods.